# Manejar múltiples imágenes en Django

Tags: python, django

Estoy intentando manejar varias imágenes, pero no lo consigo. Al enviar 1 sola no tengo problemas, pero al ser múltiples no puedo acceder a ellas.

Así envío la información desde React

```js
onSubmit={async (values) => {
                let data = new FormData();

                data.append('username', values.username);
                data.append('tittle', values.tittle);
                data.append('desc', values.desc);
                data.append('precio', values.precio);
                data.append('direccion', values.direccion);
                data.append('imagenes', values.imagenes);
                data.append('lat', values.lat);
                data.append('long', values.long);

                await axios
                    .post('http://localhost/api/estacionamiento/', data)
                    .then((response) => {
                        //navigate(`/estacionamientos/${response.data.id}`);
                    });
            }}
```

Este es el input, si uso `event.target.files[1]` puedo manejar una imagen, pero de esta forma no puedo manejar varias.

```js
<input name='imagenes'
       type='file'
       onChange={(event) =>
       formProps.setFieldValue(
       'imagenes',
       event.target.files)
      }
       multiple/>
```

un console de *values.imagenes* me devuelve esto:

```
FileList [ File, File ]
​
0: File { name: "123.jpg", lastModified: 1652645060440, size: 46265, … }
​
1: File { name: "estacionamiento.png", lastModified: 1651870164313, size: 1987001, … }
​
length: 2
```

En Django tengo

```
       def post(self, request):
         images = request.FILES.getlist('imagenes')
         js = request.POST
        
         print(js)
         print('Files: ',images)
```

Por terminal en django me muestra que *images* no devuelve nada y en el *request.POST* me muestra `imagenes: ['[object FileList]'],`

```
<QueryDict: {'username': ['xxx@gmail.com'], 'tittle': ['lindo'], 'desc': ['4324'], 'precio': ['432423'], 'direccion': ['4234 Bronx Boulevard, Bronx, Nueva York, EE. UU.'], 'imagenes': ['[object FileList]'], 'lat': ['40.8954879'], 'long': ['-73.8602381']}>
Files:  []
```